# Using Bootstrap with npm and Node.js

Tags: node.js, bootstrap-5

I'm having a difficult time understanding where/how to use Bootstrap in my nodejs project. I installed Bootstrap with npm, but how do I include it in my index.html file?

Do I need to include the stylesheet  tag at the top and the  tags above the  tag at the bottom like usual in my .html files, or can I just start applying Bootstrap classes to my elements once I've required it in my app.js file?

Also, is there an advantage to using npm to install Bootstrap versus using the CDNs?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Including the bootstrap js and css depends on how do you build your project. Could you post more information about the project? Like if you use babel etc. Or then just relevant parts of the index.html and package.json.

Comment: if you are using in nodejs then I suggest you to use npm and which render engine you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend checking out Bootstrap's npm starter project:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-npm-starter

It shows you exactly how to load it from npm and use it in a project.

It's better to build the CSS yourself (from the Sass files) so you can customise it and remove the components you don't need and creating a smaller CSS file.

Answer (score 5):

Add this code if using server like Express

```
app.use(
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/"))
);
```

Then in your head tag:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should short the path of `bootstrap` module as a `static` path like this:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("Listen to 3000");
})

app.use("/css",express.static("./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css"));
app.use("/js",express.static("./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js"));
//or
app.use("/",express.static("./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/"));
```

Then you can address to js and css like this:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

**bootstrap is ready to use!**